# The Computation of a special kind of Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N}$, we wish to compute the Laurent Series for the function
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)^k}
$$
about $z=0$ (NOT $z=a$). So there should be two Laurent Series which are valid for $|z|<|a|$ and $|z|>|a|$. Clearly if $a=0$ then this is already a Laurent Series. But what about $a\ne 0$? I can do 
$$
\frac{1}{z-a},
$$
but not quite sure how to do $(z-a)^{-k}$. Could somebody give me some clue about how to do this or give me some general methods to do this kind of question?

First for the case $|z|<|a|$, $f(z)$ is holomorphic, then it has a Taylor Series
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)^k}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}a_nz^n.
$$
Then
$$
a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}(0)}{n!}=\frac{(-1)^n(k+n-1)!}{n!(k-1)!(0-a)^{k+n}}=\frac{(-1)^k}{a^{k+n}}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.
$$
In particular, if $a=1$, then for $|z|<1$
$$
\frac{1}{(z-1)^k}=(-1)^k\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}z^n.
$$

Now if $|z|>|a|$, then $\left|\frac{1}{z}\right|<|a|$, we write
$$
f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-a)^k}=\frac{1}{(-1)^k(a-z)^k}=\frac{1}{(-1)^kz^k(\frac{a}{z}-1)^k}.
$$
From above, we know that $\left|\frac{a}{z}\right|<1$, then
$$
\frac{1}{(\frac{a}{z}-1)^k}=(-1)^k\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\left(\frac{a}{z}\right)^n.
$$
Then for $|z|>|a|$, we have
$$
f(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}\frac{a^n}{z^{n+k}}=\sum^{\infty}_{n=k}\binom{n-1}{k-1}a^{n-k}z^{-n}.
$$

Comment: If $a \neq 0$ then the Laurent series of $f(z)$ about $z=0$ will just be a Taylor series (no negative powers).  Try using the binomial theorem.

Comment: @AntonioVargas Is it always a Taylor Series? I thought if $|z|>|a|$ then this is only holomorphic on this annulus then it must have a Laurent Series with principal part non-zero.

Comment: Sorry, you're right, I was only speaking about the series valid for $|z| < |a|$.  For $|z| > |a|$ you do get a Laurent series and the binomial theorem will still get you there (after some rearrangement).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I tried to do the case $|z|>|a|$ from the case $|z|<|a|$ but I don't know if that is right. I will edit the question above :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that 
$$
\frac{1}{(z-a)^{k+1}} = \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\frac{d^{k}}{dz^{k}}\left(\frac{1}{z-a}\right)
$$
and use the fact that you can differentiate the power series of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ term by term.